# Set element in array to 0 or NULL

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

I have created an Array that is sized by user input.

```
    int spotInArray = 0;
    Bankcard* a = NULL;
    int n;           
    cout << "Enter number of cards" << std::endl;
    cin >> n;
    a = new Bankcard[n];
```

This is my code I have in my switch for the user to select which card they want to delete.

```
            int choice;
            cout << "Enter Number of card you would like to delete: " << endl;
            cin >> choice;
                for (int i = n; i < spotInArray; i++)
                {
                    a[n] = a[n + 1];
                    a[choice - 1] = 0;
                }
```

I am getting this error on a[choice - 1] = 0;

> IntelliSense: no operator "=" matches these operands

Here is the full code.

```
int main()
{
//Bankcard bankcard1("Blue Card", 1, .05, 3000.00, 430.32, 200.35, 124.00);
int spotInArray = 0;
Bankcard* a = NULL;   // Pointer to int, initialize to nothing.
int n;           // Size needed for array
cout << "Enter number of cards" << std::endl;
cin >> n;        // Read in the size
a = new Bankcard[n];  // Allocate n ints and save ptr in a.
//for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
//a[i] = bankcard1;
//bankcard1.show();
//}



int choice;

showMenu();

cin >> choice;

while (choice != 6)
{
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1  :   {
                    string productName;
                    int cardNum;
                    double interestRate;
                    double maxLimit;
                    double outstandingBalance;
                    double purchaseAmount;
                    double paymentAmount;
                    cout << "Enter Card Name(No spaces, no special characters)" << std::endl;
                    cin >> productName;

                    cout << "Enter Number of Card" << std::endl;
                    cin >> cardNum;

                    cout << "Enter interest Rate" << std::endl;
                    cin >> interestRate;

                    cout << "Enter Max Limit" << std::endl;
                    cin >> maxLimit;

                    cout << "Enter Outstanding Balance" << std::endl;
                    cin >> outstandingBalance;

                    cout << "Enter Purchase Amount" << std::endl;
                    cin >> purchaseAmount;

                    cout << "Enter Payment Amount" << std::endl;
                    cin >> paymentAmount;
                    Bankcard bankcard1(productName, cardNum, interestRate, maxLimit, outstandingBalance, purchaseAmount, paymentAmount);
                    a[spotInArray] = bankcard1;
                    spotInArray++;
                    break;
                    }

        case 2  :   update();
                    break;
        case 3  :   {
                        int choice;
                        cout << "Enter Number of card you would like to delete: " << endl;
                        cin >> choice;
                        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                        {
                            a[n] = a[n + 1];
                            a[choice - 1] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    deleteCard();
                    break;
        case 4  :   overLoad();
                    break;
        case 5  :   {
                        for ( int i = 0; i < spotInArray; i++)
                        {
                            cout << a[i];
                        }
                    }
                    break;
        case 6  :   exit();
                    break;

    }
    showMenu();
    cout << endl;
    cin >> choice;
};

std::cin.get();
std::cin.get();
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Bankcard is a class or struct, right?  You can't assign zero to a class or struct.  You're treating a[choice-1] as if it were a pointer, which it is not.

Comment: If working with C++ use std::vector instead of a C array.
Also, when removing something from you array now, you will have to free the memory allocated to the structure.
There are many issues in your code.

Comment: Somebody has to mention that [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) can simplify this quite a bit. Then you don't need to worry so much about prompting the user for size and questioning what happens when a user enters a negative (or really big) size.

Comment: Bankcard is a class and the array is filled with objects that are created by the user.

I have tried learning vectors but I am lost with them.

Comment: Recommend you go back to the basics of pointers and arrays using simple, integral types (int, char, etc).  Once you thoroughly understand how to use arrays and pointers, your errors will seem obvious.  Adding the full code wasn't really helpful.  You need to address the problems others have already pointed out.

Comment: I created a public method to force all values the user set to 0. It is working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there are other code that you haven't shown, currently this for loop shouldn't even run:

```
        for (int i = n; i < spotInArray; i++)
        {
            a[n] = a[n + 1];
            a[choice - 1] = 0;
        }
```

because `spotInArray` is `0` and `i` starts at `n` (and you are incrementing `i`, too).

Are you sure it's failing on that line?

Comment: He's not even getting to that point.  It's hitting an IntelliSense error before he even compiles it.

Comment: This is the code example I used.

for (int i = index; i < /* length */; i++)
array[index] = array[index+1];
array[length-1] = 0;

Comment: I created a public method to force all values the user set to 0. It is working now.

Answer (score 1):

There are few incorrect things with the code. First of all, `a[n]` is invalid. Valid index of array of size `n` are 0 to n-1. Avoid handling memory your self. Use `std::list` instead in this case ( if there is frequent removals ).

```
 std::list<Bankcard> bCards(n);

 // Take input to for the cardToRemove.

 bCards.erase( bCards.begin() + cardToRemove );
```

Comment: I get a: IntelliSense: no operator "+" matches these operands